# How to catch Connection Reset Error from loop.sock_recv() function?

Tags: python, sockets, exception, python-asyncio

I am trying to catch a connection reset error from the loop.sock_recv function while trying to read bytes from client socket. I am testing a scenario when server closes the connection after a specific timeout, the sock_recv(client_socket, max_rec) function throws Connection reset error as expected but i am not able to catch it in the code. Rather if i replace try/except with try/finally it works better but not always gives the expected answer.

```
 try:
            done, pending = await asyncio.wait([loop.sock_recv(client_sock, max_rec)], timeout = 7)

        except ConnectionResetError:
            log.info(f"Got the connection reset which means the server socket closed the connection after {timeout} seconds")
            is_connection_reset = True
```

The logs are

```
[[0m ERROR    16:43:05| asyncio                        - Task exception was never retrieved
[[36mtest-client_1  |^[[0m future: <Task finished name='Task-67' coro=<BaseSelectorEventLoop.sock_recv() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py:349> exception=ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')>(base_events.py, line 1707)
[[36mtest-client_1  |[[0m Traceback (most recent call last):
[[36mtest-client_1  |[[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 368, in sock_recv
[[36mtest-client_1  |[[0m     return await fut
[[36mtest-client_1  |[[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 379, in _sock_recv
[[36mtest-client_1  |[[0m     data = sock.recv(n)
[[36mtest-client_1  |[[0m ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal example that we could run to reproduce this? Are you sure the program that logs a traceback coming from `ConnectionResetError` is the one where you catch that exception? Do you perhaps have multiple places where `sock_recv` is called, and you added the try/except in only some of them?

Comment: @user4815162342 - the client_socket i am using here is used in multiple places but the exceptions are handled correctly because i remove my code i don't see any exceptions. Also when i set_exception_handler for the above code it correctly receives Error:104 Connection reset by peer. I don't have test code to verify this.

Comment: You're right; I think I understand what's going on. An answer is forthcoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `asyncio.wait([...], timeout=7)` with `asyncio.wait_for`:

```
try:
    data = await asyncio.wait_for(
        loop.sock_recv(client_sock, max_rec), 7)
except ConnectionResetError:
    ... handle connection reset
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    ... handle timeout
```

The difference between `asyncio.wait_for(x, 7)` and `asyncio.wait([x], timeout=7)` is that `wait_for` will *cancel* the awaitable if the timeout elapses. On the other hand, `asyncio.wait()` will leave it running in the background (and return it in the `pending` set).

What most likely happens in your case is that `sock_recv` raises `ConnectionResetError` after more than 7s. As written, your code only handles the error if it occurs within the first 7 seconds. If it occurs later, it will be raised in a background task and reported by the default exception handler.

On an aside note, you probably shouldn't be using `sock_recv` directly; it is a low-level API that only the implementors of new event loops should care about. Application code should use [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input and yeah you are right. I used asyncio.wait and explicitly cancelled the pending tasks to avoid those exceptions but asyncio.wait_for works much better. Now I get the asyncio.TimeoutError after the given timeout before i get the ConnectionResetError. Please note this is a coroutine so this function is getting called asynchronously. Any inputs why this is happening.

Comment: @KishoreKhan The `TimeoutError` is there to let you detect that a timeout has occurred. You just need to handle it, as shown in the answer.

Comment: Yes I am handling it in the code but in my case the connection reset should happen before the TimeoutError but it is happening the other way round. In the above example after 7 seconds the first exception is TimeoutError followed by ConnectionResetError but i expect ConnectionResetError first immediately after 7 seconds. How do i handle this ?

Comment: @KishoreKhan I'm afraid I don't quite understand that. How can you have two exceptions, one after the other? Where is the second one coming from, where do you receive it? If there is an exception (data didn't arrive), there should be exactly one exception, either `TimeoutError`, which means the coroutine timed out, or some socket-relared error (including but not limited to `ConnectionResetError`). You cannot have both, because that would mean that the code both timed out and raised before timing out. Can you show how you invoke `wait_for`, exactly?

Comment: Sorry if that question mislead you. I run a while loop until a flag becomes true which happens only when a ConnectionResetError happens. So the while loop repeats until the flag is set to True. This is why TimeoutError happens repeatedly until we receive a ConnectionResetError exception. I found the issue that i made in one of the configurations on the server socket to send data. It is all fine and working the way it is expected to. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KishoreKhan If the issue is resolved, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/627709) the answer.

Comment: i did, was wondering how to accept the answer. thanks for the link.